# How to kill a process running on server

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

I am using run_command shell program to run some commands on servers from client machine, this shell program runs particular command on server by socket communication. In Server side i use java program to run command on server, Normally for commands like ls , `pwd` it is working good , but for commands like `"tail -f"`  though i am pressing `ctrl^c` to stop a command, it is not stopping in server side.

1. is there any way to to capture  ctrl^c so that i will send some msg that kills running command on server
2. to kill some command on server , how can i kill only that particular command which was run from client not any other

Answer (score 1):

Use kill command. For more information please refer URL [Kill Command for UNIX](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-kill-unix-process-with-kill-command/)

Comment: I know that kill will do the job,that i already mentioned, i asked how to use it, and is there any other option...

Comment: # kill -9 'id of process'

Comment: how can i get proccess id of proccess which was running on server, and  also i asked that i need capture ctrl^c operation , whenever user do ctlr^c operation then automatically kill command should be send..

Answer (score 1):

first of all, I assume that for some reason you cannot run kill on that run_command thing. If you can, ignore below answer.

On the server, start Process. Wrap the Process object along with an ID (auto generated). Add wrapper to a List or Map. Display the ID to user on client.

when user wants to kill process, send something like "mykill ". On server, if command.equals("mykill"), then get the Process indicated by id and call its destroy method, and remove from list. Also remove stale processes from your list (whether running or exited, just to keep your list or map from getting too big).

> > I am using run_command shell program to run some commands on servers from client machine, this shell program runs particular command on server by socket communication.

I assume there is a good reason you are not using putty. I also assume you can modify the code of that server.

Please note I have not tried this myself. I am just giving ideas.

Comment: i am using putty , In putty from client side i am executing shell program "run_command -s 192.168.1.91 -c ls" ; After running command, In server side i have one java program which accepts this command and runs on that server, problem is i dont have direct access to server so when i execute commands like tail -f from client and press  ctr^c though shell is exited in client's putty but command still running on server, which takes load... , i cant kill any process as others may have run same command at server side ... that is the problem

Comment: allright.. so now, if you can modify the java program on the server, then what I suggested might work. The java program might be creating Process and starting it. Note that the java program is not a command line as such. So even if you are able to send a Ctrl C to the server, it may not treat it as such. You will have to wrap Process and give it some auto incremented ID. print that id (e.g. 123) on run_command client. when you type command as run_command -s 192.168.1.91 -c mykill 123, it will kill process 123.

Comment: Can you not open another putty session/window, and say run_command ps -ef|grep tail . Once you have the pid, use run_command kill id. I guess you will have to close the previous putty session/window.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for this

```
killall `pidof ProcessName`
```